# ViewController with subviews, UIScrollView not scrollable first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im using a `UIViewController` with several subviews from XIBs, (ViewController's views), they are chosen between using `UISegmentedControl`. One of these views are containing a `UIScrollView`. The problem is that the `UIScrollView` is not scrollable the *first time* this subview is added. If I choose another segment/view and then the one with the `UIScrollView` again, now it's scrollable.

The `UIScrollView` is added in IB only. This is some of the codes for the views and UISegmentedControl in MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

nameSubViewController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
nameSubView = (NameSubView *)[nameSubViewController view];

priceSubViewController = [[PriceSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PriceSubViewController" bundle:nil];
priceSubView = (PriceSubView *)[priceSubViewController view];

[self.view addSubview:nameSubView];
currentView = nameSubView;
}

- (void) segmentAction:(id)sender
{
segmentedControl = sender;
if([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:nameSubView];
    currentView = nil;
    currentView = nameSubView;
}
if([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 1) {
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:priceSubView];
    currentView = nil;
    currentView = priceSubView;
}
```

In this code, let's say segment 1 (`priceSubView`) contains the UIScrollView. If I choose this segment, the `UIScrollView` does not react on the scrolling unless I choose segment 0 (`nameSubView`) again and re-select segment 1.

What is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: try [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES]; in viewDidAppear

Comment: How does `PriceSubViewController` look like? My imaginative scenario is that `scrollView.contentSize` is somehow set before the correct contentSize is figured out.

Comment: I think you are adding the scroll view only after the segment is changed. At the first load you are not adding the scrollView, am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to scroll at first load.
You need to add the scrollView at firstLoad.
You are adding the scroll view after changing the segment control, that's why it's not scrolling. Check it out.

Change `viewDidLoad` like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  nameSubViewController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
  nameSubView = (NameSubView *)[nameSubViewController view];

  priceSubViewController = [[PriceSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PriceSubViewController" bundle:nil];
  priceSubView = (PriceSubView *)[priceSubViewController view];

  [self.view addSubview:priceSubView];
  currentView = priceSubView;
}
```